# error reporting on specific folders

Tags: php, error-reporting

is there a way to set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` for a specific directory rather than including it in each file?

I'd like to turn on error reporting for my beta.mysite.com

Comment: I wish I can chose 2 posts for valid answers +1 for all three :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You can use a .htaccess file in Apache](https://www.php.net/configuration.changes).  Just add this line:

```
php_value error_reporting 6143
```

Or for old PHP versions:

```
php_value error_reporting 2047
```

Note that you can't use the contants (like E_ALL)

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting):

> **Note: PHP Constants outside of PHP**
>
> Using PHP Constants outside of PHP,
> like in httpd.conf, will have no
> useful meaning so in such cases the
> integer values are required. And since
> error levels will be added over time,
> the maximum value (for E_ALL) will
> likely change. So in place of E_ALL
> consider using a larger value to cover
> all bit fields from now and well into
> the future, a numeric value like
> 2147483647.

Comment: +1 for being so dang detailed, but I added in the bit that points to the config, remove if you don't like

Answer (score 3):

[Use an .htaccess file to set the option.](https://www.php.net/configuration.changes)

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  display_errors 1
</IfModule>
```

Now, naturally this only works if you are using apache as a module.

If you want to add the configuration option when using CGI, your options going to be limited.

A couple of ideas:

- Including something in every script.
- More exotic: Use a rewrite rule which pointed to a known script in the directory which did the usual `set_ini` style argument, and then included the intended script by checking the path. I'm bad with rewrite rules, but I know this could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note: putting PHP instructions into .htaccess works only if PHP is installed as an Apache module. With PHP installed as CGI all you get is a `500 Internal server error`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm on apache but if someone else was reading this; how would you do it under CGI?

Comment: Right now I'm using per-directory php.ini files at my shared Linux host. Up to now I've been unable to have the same thing working on my home-based WIndows test server: I believe it requires phpsuexec or suphp running on Apache.
If nothing else works I'd resort to include() or auto_prepend a php file with a list of ini_set() instructions at the start of every file...

Answer (score 0):

for CGI mode you must use php.ini to accomplish that