# How to hide a table row in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table such as this

```
<table class="headerTable" id="headerTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="hh">
            <td>test1</td>
            <td>18,164</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="member">
            <td>test3</td>
            <td>24,343</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to hide the rows with class member.

I did something like this but it is not working..

```
$("#headerTable tbody tr:member").hide();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#headerTable tbody tr.member").hide();
```

The selectors in jQuery like CSS selectors, so you should be able to use them like that.

You can browse the [jQuery selector documentation here](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors), it's full of interesting things you can do.

Answer (score 4):

**To specify a class using CSS use a dot to signify that it's a class, not a colon.** The colon is used by jQuery for filters.

```
$("tr.member").hide();
```

Is just fine unless you want to be specific to a table.

Comment: Could I encourage you to upvote Olafur's response since you both provided the same solution, but he was first?

Comment: He could have been writing his answer while I was writing mine.

Comment: I leave it alone unless it's significantly different in some way, say it's more detailed. For instance, I upvoted the other answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049326/php-error-reporting-on-specific-folders

Comment: I am curious about others approach as well. Joel or Jeff has suggested that high rep users tend to vote things up more often than non-high-rep users (which isn't surprising as they tend to just be more active in general) - and I do find myself running out of votes after a while, but I do try to let nature take it's course on questions I am answering.

Comment: Anyway, I have to censor, cause these comments belong on uservoice ;)

Comment: What I see happening also is the top question getting voted up much more regardless of the quality of answer 2 through n. 2 through n get votes of course but the top answer often gets 2-3x the votes.

Comment: Ólafur has the answer and it's succinct, and now quite informative.  However, this answer outlines the *problem* that the user had, does it clearly, and for that reason deserves a +1.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `find`.

```
$('#headerTable').find('.member').hide();
```

Or if all the rows (elements, actually) with class `member` should be hidden:

```
$('.member').hide();
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

$("#headerTable .member").hide();