# How to hide a table row with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I am trying to hide a table row with jQuery instead of with js as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669256/how-to-hide-a-row-of-table-or-a-list-item-and-update-the-datastore-without-relo). This is the script that I put in the header:

```
self.response.out.write("""
    <html>
    <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" /> 
    <title>User Admin Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#false").click(function() {
        $("#hide").hide("slow");
    });
});
</script>
<body>
""")
```

And here is the html:

```
...
<tr class="hide">
 <td>
  ...
   <a class="false" href="/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false"><span class="small">(hide)</span></a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</div>
...
```

This is not working. And this question is [same as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049357/how-to-hide-a-table-row-in-jquery) but I cannot make mine work.  What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Edited code according to answers. But this is still not working although it is working in jsfiddle:

```
         <html><head>
         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" /> 
         <title>User Admin Page</title>
         <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">

<script>


 $(document).ready(function() {

     $("a.false").click(function(e) {
     $(".hide").hide("slow");
     e.preventDefault();
          });

 });   </script> </head>
         <body>
 ...
```

**Update**

The closing `</script>` was missing in the CDN call; but now the entire table is hidden; I am adding that section of the table. Thanks again for the answers:

```
    self.response.out.write("""<table class="mytable">
    <tr class="head">
    <th  width="80%">links</th><th>edit tags</th>
    </tr>    
    """)        

    query = Main.all()
    query.filter("owner", user)
    query.filter("display", True)
    query.order("-date")
    cursor = self.request.get("cursor")
    if cursor: query.with_cursor(cursor)
    e = query.fetch(100)
    cursor = query.cursor()

    for item in e:
        main_id = item.key().id()
        self.response.out.write("""
        <tr class="hide">
        <td><a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a><span class=small> (%s) </span><br />
        <span class=small>%s</span>
        <a href="/edit?main_id=%s"><span class="small">(edit)</span></a>
        <a class="false" href="/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false"><span class="small">(hide)</span></a>
        <a href="/comment?main_id=%s"><span class="small">(comments)</span></a></td>
        <td><a href="/tc?url=%s&main_id=%s&user_tag_list=%s" title="edit tags">%s</a>
        </td>
        </tr>
        """ % tuple([item.url, item.title, urlparse(item.url).netloc,
        f1.truncate_at_space(item.pitch), main_id, main_id, main_id,
        item.url, main_id, (", ".join(item.tag_list)),
        (", ".join(item.tag_list)),]))


    self.response.out.write("""</tbody></table>""")
```

Comment: @ mu is too short: No, that was from earlier version; I updated the question. But this is still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, you have `false` as a `class` in your HTML

`<a class="false" href=...`

and an `ID` in your script

`$("#false").click(function()...`

Your `hide` is also an `id` and should be `class`.

**Here is the fix:** http://jsfiddle.net/A6jKm/1/

---

**EDIT**

> now it hides the entire table

That's because all your rows are generated with the same `hide` class, as seen here

```
for item in e:
    main_id = item.key().id()
    self.response.out.write("""
    <tr class="hide">
```

To get around this, I've modified the code a bit to search for the direct parent of the clicked item:

```
$("a.false").click(function(e){
    $(this).parents('tr').hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Updated Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/A6jKm/3/

---

**EDIT 2**

Perhaps `closest` would work better.

Try this

```
$("a.false").click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('tr.hide').hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Example 3:** http://jsfiddle.net/A6jKm/4/

Comment: @ Jason: Thanks. I must be doing something wrong in another part of the code because this is not working in the Google App Engine although it is working in jsfiddle. Is there something wrong with the header? Thanks again.

Comment: What happens if you remove that `div` around the `tr` in the original HTML above?  It should not make a difference... but?

Comment: You might also want to update the CDN call.  Instead of `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js`, use `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @ Jason: Thanks, I did that, that wasn't the problem but I noticed that the closing `</script>` was missing, when I added that it now works, but now it hides the entire table. Do you know why? I will update the question with the rest of the code.

Comment: Can I pass the `main_id` to jQuery from the url and hide only that row by using that id?

Comment: @ Jason: Now the entire table, including the holding table, is hidden. I found this parser http://plugins.jquery.com/project/parseQuery to get the query string; I wonder if that would help. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zeynel, I changed the js one more time.  Refer to the edit and see if that works.

Comment: Yes, this one works. Many thanks for the help. I now want to send the `main_id` of the hidden item to the database with an ajax call, but I'll ask that separately.

Answer (score 1):

You're using ID selectors:

```
$("#false").click(function() {
    $("#hide").hide("slow");
});
```

when you want a class selectors:

```
$(".false").click(function() {
    $(".hide").hide("slow");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/sw7Tr/