# How to update database with jQuery without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I send this `display_false()` function to the server with jQuery so that the database is updated without refreshing the page?

```
    def display_false():
        if display == "false":
            main_id = self.request.get("main_id")
            k = Main.get_by_id(int(main_id))
            k.display = False
            k.put()

    display_false()
```

First I hide a table row with this jQuery ([see my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694560/how-to-hide-a-table-row-with-jquery)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.false").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest("tr.hide").hide("slow");
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

and then I want to update the "display" property in the database to "false" with `display_false()`so that the item is not displayed.

And this is the html where the hide link is:

```
    for item in e:
        main_id = item.key().id()
        ...
        <tr class="hide">
        ...
        <a class="false" href="/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false"><span class="small">(hide)</span></a>
        ...
        </td>
        </tr>
        ...
```

Thanks!

**Update**

This is what I tried according to [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696540/how-to-update-database-with-jquery-without-refreshing-the-page/7696578#7696578), but this is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //hide the row
    $("a.false").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest("tr.hide").hide("slow");
    e.preventDefault();


});

    $("a.false").click(function() {
    //ajax server call
    $.ajax({
    url: "/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false",
    success: function(data) {
    //do some stuff.
    display_false()
    alert('returned');
  }
});
});


});
```

**Update**

I put alerts to see what is running as suggested by Paul. Alerts 1, 2 and 3 are running but 4 is not running:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("1 - document ready is called")
    $("a.false").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest("tr.hide").hide("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("2 - row is hidden")

});

    $("a.false").click(function() {
    //ajax server call
    alert("3 - ajax server call")
    $.ajax({
    url: "/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false",
    success: function(data) {
    //do some stuff.
    display_false()
    alert(4 - "returned");
  }
});
});


});
```

**Update**

This is the part of the code for that section of the table; I am trying to get the `main_id` and pass it to ajax call:

```
#-----------main table------------#

            main_id = self.request.get("main_id")

            self.response.out.write("""<table class="mytable">
            <tr class="head">
            <th  width="80%">links</th><th>edit tags</th>
            </tr>    
            """)        

            query = Main.all()
            query.filter("owner", user)
            query.filter("display", True)
            query.order("-date")
            cursor = self.request.get("cursor")
            if cursor: query.with_cursor(cursor)
            e = query.fetch(100)
            cursor = query.cursor()

            for item in e:
                main_id = item.key().id()
                self.response.out.write("""
                <tr class="hide">
                <td><a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a><span class=small> (%s) </span><br />
                <span class=small>%s</span>
                <a href="/edit?main_id=%s"><span class="small">(edit)</span></a>
                <a class="false" href="/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false"><span class="small">(hide)</span></a>
                <a href="/comment?main_id=%s"><span class="small">(comments)</span></a></td>
                <td><a href="/tc?url=%s&main_id=%s&user_tag_list=%s" title="edit tags">%s</a>
                </td>
                </tr>
                """ % tuple([item.url, item.title, urlparse(item.url).netloc,
                f1.truncate_at_space(item.pitch), main_id, main_id, main_id,
                item.url, main_id, (", ".join(item.tag_list)),
                (", ".join(item.tag_list)),]))

            self.response.out.write("""</tbody></table>""")    

            display = self.request.get("display")
            def display_false():
                if display == "false":
                    main_id = self.request.get("main_id")
                    k = Main.get_by_id(int(main_id))
                    k.display = False

                    k.put()

            display_false()
```

**Update after discussion with Paul to get the id number of the hidden row:**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("1 - document ready is called")

    $("a.false").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest("tr.hide").hide("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("2 - row is hidden")
});



    $("a.false").click(function() {

    alert(this.attr("title"));

    $.ajax({
    url: "/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false",

    success: function(data) {
    display_false()
    alert(4 - "returned");
  }
});
});
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot update a server database with JQuery. All you can do is send a request that is handled by the server.

Use JQuery.Ajax or any spin-offs of that function to send the request. To your server it will look as a regular request.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need an AJAX call, something like this after including your jQuery libraries.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//false click action
$("a.false").click(function () { 

//ajax server call
$.ajax({
  url: '/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false',
  success: function(data) {
    //do some stuff.
    alert('returned');
  }
});

});



});
```

Comment: @ Paul: Thanks. I put my function `display_false()` where you indicated `//do some stuff` but this is not running the function. I updated the code with what I did. What am I doing wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: What is running? How far are you getting through the above? Use alert statements to debug, firstly, is document ready() getting called - i.e. jQuery loading ok. Secondly, is the handler for a.false click firing, again, try alerting. Once you've got that far, see is the ajax call firing. Walk your way through the code to narrow down the error.


BTW, everything needs to be inside document ready.

Comment: @ Paul: I added the alerts. document ready() is called but the section with alert("returned") is not called. Am I putting my function in the right place? Updated the question with alerts.

Comment: @ Paul: Now I have the request running but I get an error because the main_id in the url is not the id anymore. How do I pass the main_id to the url? If the main_id of the row to hide is 1053, the url sent to ajax needs to be url: '/useradminpage?main_id=1053&display=false' How can I do this? (I hard-coded the main_id=1053 and it worked).

Comment: You'll probably need to include that main id somewhere in your HTML so it can be referenced by jQuery and added to the request URL. Add it as say as a 'title' attribute of your table row. then pick it off by referencing the this variable in the click event.



<tr class="hide" title="1053">

Comment: have a look at the jQuery documentation for referencing elements, but alerting should return the 'particular' link clicked, from that, use a selector to get the table row, and then the ID.

$("a.false").click(function () { alert(this) });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4106/discussion-between-paul-and-zeynel)