# How to pass a query string to Ajax call with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

This is a follow up to [my previous question (unresolved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696540/how-to-update-database-with-jquery-without-refreshing-the-page).

I fetch `items` from the database and display them in a for loop. I use jQuery to hide one of the rows. Now I need to get the `main_id` of that hidden row and pass it to `$.ajax`. In the original question Paul suggested to use `alert(this.attr("title"));` but this line stops the execution of the `$.ajax` call and the call is not executed. When I comment out the alert `alert(this.attr("title"));` then the ajax call goes through. In that case, I get an error because the `display_false()` function in the handler does not get the value of the `main_id`.

This is the html of the "hide" link with `title=%s`.

```
<a class="false" title=%s href="/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false"><span class="small">(hide)</span></a>
```

So I need to pass the value of the `main_id` stored in `alert(this.attr("title"));` to the function `display_false()` when the ajax call is executed.

How can I do this?

The relevant code is below:

**The Script**

```
        self.response.out.write("""
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" /> 
<title>User Admin Page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    alert("1 - document ready is called")
    $("a.false").click(function(e) {
        $(this).closest("tr.hide").hide("slow");
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("2 - row is hidden")
    });

    $("a.false").click(function() {
        alert("3 - ajax")
        //the following alert stops the ajax call from executing
        alert(this.attr("title"));

        $.ajax({
            url: "/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false",
            data: {main_id: "title"}
            success: function(data) {
            display_false()
            alert(4 - "returned");
            }
        });
    });
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
""")
```

**HTML**

```
#-----------main table------------#
            main_id = self.request.get("main_id")

            self.response.out.write("""<table class="mytable">
            <tr class="head">
            <th  width="80%">links</th><th>edit tags</th>
            </tr>    
            """)        

            query = Main.all()
            query.filter("owner", user)
            query.filter("display", True)
            query.order("-date")
            cursor = self.request.get("cursor")
            if cursor: query.with_cursor(cursor)
            e = query.fetch(100)
            cursor = query.cursor()

            for item in e:
                main_id = item.key().id()
                self.response.out.write("""
                <tr class="hide">
                <td><a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a><span class=small> (%s) </span><br />
                <span class=small>%s</span>
                <a href="/edit?main_id=%s"><span class="small">(edit)</span></a>
                <a class="false" title=%s href="/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false"><span class="small">(hide)</span></a>
                <a href="/comment?main_id=%s"><span class="small">(comments)</span></a></td>
                <td><a href="/tc?url=%s&main_id=%s&user_tag_list=%s" title="edit tags">%s</a>
                </td>
                </tr>
                """ % tuple([item.url, item.title, urlparse(item.url).netloc,
                f1.truncate_at_space(item.pitch), main_id, 

                main_id,

                main_id, main_id,
                item.url, main_id, (", ".join(item.tag_list)),
                (", ".join(item.tag_list)),]))

            self.response.out.write("""</tbody></table>""")    

            display = self.request.get("display")

            def display_false():
                if display == "false":
                    main_id = self.request.get("main_id")
                    #I tried to get the "title" but this does not work
                    #main_id = self.request.get("title")
                    k = Main.get_by_id(int(main_id))
                    k.display = False                    
                    k.put()

            display_false()    
            ...
```

**Update**

Updated the code according to [James Montagne's answer (with a few changes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698706/how-to-pass-a-query-string-to-ajax-call-with-jquery/7698722#7698722). Now, for some reason, document ready is not loading, and the call to hide the row is not working, but ajax call to update the database is working. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    alert("1 - document ready is called")
    $("a.false").click(function(e) {
        $(this).closest("tr.hide").hide("slow");
        var main_id = this.attr("title");
        var display = "false";
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("2 - row is hidden")
    });

    $("a.false").click(function() {
        alert("3 - ajax");

        $.ajax({
            url: "/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false",
            data: {main_id: "main_id", display: "display")},
            success: function(data) {
            display_false()
            alert(4 - "returned");
            }
        });
    });
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to alert that value, you need to pass it.  Currently you are passing the string `title`.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false",
        data: {main_id: this.attr("title")}
        success: function(data) {
        display_false()
        alert(4 - "returned");
        }
    });
```

Comment: @ James Montagne: Thanks for the answer. I noticed that I needed to take the `main_id` from the first click from the hide function otherwise the `main_id` is always the id of the last item in the list. But now hide function is not working although database is now updating. Any suggestions? Also I added a comma at the end of the data line. Is that correct? I edited the question with updated code. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, there was an extra parenthesis, document ready is now loading but hide function still is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    alert("1 - document ready is called")
    $("a.false").click(function(e) {
        $(this).closest("tr.hide").hide("slow");
        var main_id = this.attr("title");
        var display = "false";
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("2 - row is hidden")
    });

    $("a.false").click(function() {
        alert("3 - ajax");

        $.ajax({
            url: "/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false",
            data: {main_id: "main_id", display: "display")},
            success: function(data) {
            display_false()
            alert(4 - "returned");
            }
        });
    });
});


</script>
```