# Ajax jquery request fail?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iis

**My $.ajax jquery request is**

```
$.ajax({
   url: "my_url/GetBill.aspx",
   dataType: 'json',
   data : { target : codetype , number : boxnumber, mobile : mobile } , 
   success: jsonpCallback,
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Done : " + msg );
})
.fail(function( msg) {
  alert(fail_message)
})
.always(function( msg ) {
  
});

});
```

But it work properly on request via url as :

```
      my_url/GetBill.aspx?target=codetype&number=boxnumber&mobile=mobile
```

Should something change in IIS or is it something else?

Comment: According to my test, I think it is not caused by IIS but script. The url can work but script didnot work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may need to change the url value "my_url/GetBill.aspx" to be sth like "my_url/GetBill.aspx?target=%s&number=%d&mobile=%s"

Reference: [How to pass a query string to Ajax call with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698706/how-to-pass-a-query-string-to-ajax-call-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you missing a few things.

Assuming a web page, and say this:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Sub SendName2(FirstName As String, LastName As String)

    Debug.Print("FirstName = " & FirstName)
    Debug.Print("LastName = " & LastName)

End Sub
```

Ok, then the ajax call will be this:

```
        function mywebcall() {
            var MyFirstName = 'Albert';
            var MyLastName = 'Kallal';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: 'JsDialog.aspx/SendName2',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({FirstName: MyFirstName, LastName: MyLastName }),
                success: mydone
            });
        }

        function mydone() {
            alert('all done');
        }
```

So NOTE VERY careful. You choose/set the Web method in the URL.

So, in above, my URL is JsDialog.aspx, and the web method is the name of the shared function (in c#, that is "static"). So the web method must be declared as static, since a instance of the form's class object does NOT exist in the context of a web call.

You also need to set the content type.

Note also how I passed the two values (use stringify - it makes the data passing a lot easier).

Note how the simple strong typed Sub parameters names are the same ones used in the data passed - so VERY nice, and VERY easy.

Running the above code will result in this output (debug window).

```
FirstName = Albert
LastName = Kallal
```

That web page needs a Imports System.Web.Services