# How to pass data to a separate program using javascript or html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a program that will prompt you to enter someone's name. Then it will take that name and send it to a different program where it will add that name to its database. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name="customerForm" action="" method="get">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br />
<input type="button" name="button" value="Add Customer" onClick="addCustomer(this.form)">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addCustomer(form)
{
    var x = form.firstname.value;
    var y = form.lastname.value;
    var name = x+" "+y;
    alert(name);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently I have the javascript function to put the name into an alert box to see if it worked.

Comment: What's the question? How to send the data to the server?

Comment: Be clear which program,language etc.

Comment: I am using javascript and html to find a solution and pass the data (aka the name) into a SQL server database.

Comment: How can this question have 3 votes up?

Comment: How can this question have 2 downvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the URI to the program in the `action` attribute and change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`.

The specifics of reading the data will depend on the language you write the program in and how it interacts with the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

[Save to database via Ajax using jQuery, php, mysql](http://www.myphpetc.com/2010/01/save-to-database-via-ajax-using-jquery.html)

So you can use Ajax on jQuery to send a form result to a PHP page, then you have to write the PHP to handle converting that data and sending it to your database.

Exmample of sending with jQuery Ajax, from [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696540/how-to-update-database-with-jquery-without-refreshing-the-page)

```
//ajax server call
$.ajax({
  url: '/useradminpage?main_id=%s&display=false',
  success: function(data) {
  //do some stuff.
  alert('returned');
 }
});
```