# Can html5 send data to a different program?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a html file that prompts you to enter a name. It will then take that name and add it to a SQL server database. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name="customerForm" action="" method="get">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" /><br />
<input type="button" name="button" value="Add Customer" onClick="addCustomer(this.form)">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addCustomer(form)
{
    var x = form.firstname.value;
    var y = form.lastname.value;
    var name = x+" "+y;
    alert(name);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently I have the javascript function to put the name into an alerty box to see if it worked.

I understand the html side of the program. What I don't know is any kind of technology or efficient method to add the data into a SQL server database.

If anybody is willing to help, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: This question is way too general for SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass data to a separate program using javascript or html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086045/how-to-pass-data-to-a-separate-program-using-javascript-or-html)

Comment: It is pretty much a duplicate. I am new to SO so I don't know if I am not supposed to duplicate posts. However, I did not get a response that was helpful to me and the old question was not getting any traction. I apologize if this caused any problems and will keep in mind to not repeat the same mistake.

Comment: @blazinazian — Comment on answers if they aren't clear or detailed enough for you. Edit your question if it needs clarification. Don't repeat yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a server-side technology like ASP.NET, PHP, or something similar to take your form submission and do something with it on the server side.

There may be some kind of jQuery plugin of some sort to do this, but you would be better suited to learn one of the above technologies.

Is there some sort of reason why you cannot use a server-side technology?

Comment: No, I am just unfamiliar with the technologies that you mentioned. I guess I will have to start learning them if I want to complete this project of mine. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use POST-request to some kind of server-side scripts written in Python/Perl/PHP/Ruby/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `button` with `submit`, set a URI in the `action` attribute, and that is the program that the data will be submitted to.

You need an interface between it and your webserver. The specifics of that will depend on your server and choice of language. [CGI](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875) is a simple, generic method (but rather inefficient). [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/) is a more complex and efficient alternative. There are also language/server specific interfaces such as [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/) and [mod_php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php).  If I was starting a project today, I'd probably write it in Perl and use [PSGI/Plack](http://plackperl.org/) to give me flexibility in how I deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Html5 works on the client-side.
You can use Webstorage (http://davidwalsh.name/html5-storage) if it fits your needs, but to persist data in another server, you have to send it.