# Display PHP errors on only one site

Tags: php, nginx, error-reporting

I've got a dev environment and a live environment running on the same host, using nginx with fastcgi. In php.ini, `display_errors` is set to off, so that the errors aren't displayed on the production site.

Now, on the dev environment, I need to be able to see those errors. So I'd do `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`, however, if it's a parse error, that won't be executed and the error won't be shown.

So my question is, is there any way I can safely set `display_errors` to on in my php.ini file, and then maybe use the virtual host file in nginx to make sure that the errors aren't shown on the production site?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049326/php-error-reporting-on-specific-folders

Comment: Unfortunately not, as I'm not using Apache.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107828/how-can-i-turn-on-php-errors-display-on-just-a-subfolder
You can solve this with .htaccess

Comment: nginx does not have .htaccess support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using fastcgi you could configure it to run php with different php.ini files. I'm not familiar with nginx and fastcgi config, so can't provide you any hint on that. See [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) to learn how PHP could be run.

I think you might want to run it like `php -d display_errors=On` for dev environment

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Looking into how to set that for a single virtual host now. If anyone has any ideas on how to do that, do chime in.

Comment: One of my coworkers figured it out. He had to set up a separate php-cgi daemon.

Comment: Use php-fpm and setup different "pools" with different sockets/ports and then you can load up specific settings per pool.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set the error reporting level directly in your script using [error_report](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).  I don't have any of my code on hand to check for certain, but I know you can change it without touching php.ini.

Comment: error_report only dictates what will be reported. display_errors decides whether or not the errors are shown at all. The problem with any of those solutions is that when the scripts are run using CGI, the script is never run if there's a parse error. Since the script isn't run, display_error is never set - and the error won't be shown.